# Decouple and Dockerize Django and Celery

Tags: django, docker, celery, django-celery

I am wondering what is the best way to decouple Celery from Django in order to dockerize the two parts and use [docker swarm service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/)? Typically one starts their celery workers and celery beat using a command that references there Django application:

```
celery worker -A my_app
celery beat -A my_app
```

From this I believe celery picks up config info from settings file and a celery.py file which is easy to move to a microservice. What I don't totally understand is how the tasks would leverage the Django ORM? Or is that not really the microservices mantra and Celery should be designed to make GET/POST calls to Django REST Framework API for the data it needs to complete the task?

Comment: have you found any information on this? I am similarly looking to move my django/celery app to use swarm, but am running into a lot of issues properly dockerizing it, would love to hear if you've had any successes!

Comment: http://matthewminer.com/2015/02/21/pattern-for-async-task-queue-results.html

Answer (score 2):

I use a setup where the code for both the django app and its celery workers is the same (as in a single repository).

When deploying I make sure to have the same code release everywhere, to avoid any surprises with the ORM, etc...

`Celery` starts with a reference to the django app, so that it has access to the models, etc...

Communication between the workers and the main app happens either through the messaging queue (`rabbitmq` or `redis`...) or via the database (as in, the celery worker works directly in the db, since it knows the models, etc...).

I'm not sure if that follows the microservices mantra, but it does work :)

Answer (score 0):

Celery's `.send_task` or `.signature` might be helpful:
https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/06/19/call-celery-task-outside-codebase/